# Is it possible to use Firefox Sync to synchronize Thunderbird plugins and accounts?

Tags: sync, thunderbird

I have a machine on which my Thunderbird is configured for three accounts (IMAP and NNTP, but NO POP).

How could I have those accounts available on other machines using Thunderbird ? I obviously would also like to have my Thunderbird extensions managed automatically (typically Lightning, which would use my GMX calendar).

I would prefer to use Firefox sync, but it doesn't seems to be available for Thunderbird. is there a way to make use of that excellent sync tool ? If not, I guess I could go the file sync way (using Dropbox or any other solution), but I would vastly prefer the sync to be done with Mozilla solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug has been open since 2008, but unfortunately this feature is still in the early stages.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446444

Mozilla hasn't been working very much on new features for Thunderbird since 2012, so it's doubtful this will happen any time soon.

http://www.zdnet.com/article/mozilla-scraps-thunderbird-development-email-client-not-a-priority-anymore/

Related question on AskUbuntu:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/497255/sync-thunderbird-configs-across-computers